# MongoDB query child collection's embedded object

Tags: .net, mongodb

I'm scratching my head for several hours and can't figure out how can I query the following document by price.amount

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f148bb56858c43428f0666b"),
  "Date" : new Date("Sat, 13 Sep 2014 00:42:29 GMT +04:00"),
  "Items" : [{
      "ProductId" : ObjectId("4f14873f6858c42ce82968e6"),
      "Quantity" : 5,
      "Price" : {
        "Amount" : "4929",
        "Currency" : "USD"
      }
    },     }, {
      "ProductId" : ObjectId("4f14873f6858c42ce829692b"),
      "Quantity" : 10,
      "Price" : {
        "Amount" : "140",
        "Currency" : "USD"
      }
    }],
  "CustomerId" : ObjectId("4f1487f16858c419c04ec2e2")
}
```

I want to select all objects which has min 1 Price item with amount > 10 for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> db.objects.find({'Items.Price.Amount':{$gt:"10"}}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4f148bb56858c43428f0666b"),
        "Date" : ISODate("2014-09-12T20:42:29Z"),
        "Items" : [
                {
                        "ProductId" : ObjectId("4f14873f6858c42ce82968e6"),
                        "Quantity" : 5,
                        "Price" : {
                                "Amount" : "4929",
                                "Currency" : "USD"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "ProductId" : ObjectId("4f14873f6858c42ce829692b"),
                        "Quantity" : 10,
                        "Price" : {
                                "Amount" : "140",
                                "Currency" : "USD"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "CustomerId" : ObjectId("4f1487f16858c419c04ec2e2")
}
```

Your "Amount" field is of type string (which I'm assuming is wrong). As such you need to compare with a string value as is shown in my example query. Obviously this will produce rather unpredictable results if you actually want to compare integers. If so, convert both the "Amount" field and the $gt value in your query to numbers.

Comment: Thanks Remon, I already tried that but didn't work. That's why I'm asking here :)

Comment: It most certainly does kind sir ;). What isn't working about it? You are aware your "Amount" values are strings?

Comment: Hmm I didn't notice that it was string. Probably that's the cause of the problem. But how could this happen, I used latest .NET driver and the Amount property on Price class is decimal... :S Anyway, the query you gave me doesn't return any result. I will try to add new objects by hand and let you know the result. Thanks again :)

Comment: The query is definitely correct if the example document you provided is correct. What do you mean with "decimal"? Is it typed as integer or a Decimal utility wrapper? It's entirely possible the latter might be converted to string.

Comment: Damn, looks like MongoDB doesn't understand decimal type. Switched to double and now it works. Thanks Remon, without you I'd have lost more hours :)

Comment: No problem ;) By the way, double is a bad type for currency due to rounding errors. It's usually better to store monetary amounts is amount of cents for example.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET MongoDB driver serializes the Decimal type to a String. This way, it can store the Decimal without loosing any precision/data when reading the Decimal from MongoDB.

Choosing another numeric type will solve your problem.